# Verifying Credit Card Number (beyond format)

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net

When asking for a credit card for Authorize.net ARB, how do you verify the card is able to be charged against?

I was looking around and saw that the common thing to do is to do a 0.00 AIM charge. Here is what I tried (the following class is from the latest AuthNet PHP SDK):

```
$authorization = new AuthorizeNetAIM;

$authorization->setFields(
   array(
     'amount' => '0.00',
     'card_num' => $credit_card_number,
     'exp_date' => $expiration_date,
   )
);

$response = $authorization->authorizeOnly();
```

While this code works and throws an error for invalid card numbers, when I put in a -real- number, it response with the following error:

> This processor does not accept zero
>   dollar authorization for this card
>   type.

Alright, so, charge .01 cents. Then, it says the transaction was successful, telling me the card is good to go and proceed creating an ARB subscription.

If I need to charge a penny, is this actually transacted on the Authorize.net side? I don't want to actually charge a penny to someones account. Does auth_only transaction type simply authorize the card? Is there a way to immediately void it after getting a successful response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an error doing $0.00 auths then your processor isn't up to speed yet on the new requirements and then you will have to do an AUTH_ONLY for $0.01 and then run a void immediately after. The void is required and is done with the AIM API as well.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually reading your blog posts, but it seems the API has changed a bit.

Comment: It seems that if the card number is right, I can enter any expiration date in the future and it still accepts the card. Is there a way to not have that happen?

Comment: Expiration date is not necessarily a factor in approving or rejecting a transaction. So as long as you enter a non-expired expiration date the odds are it will be approved (assuming nothing else makes it decline).